# Regex to match previous names

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have been having some trouble writing regex to match previous names on this page: http://steamcommunity.com/id/TripleThreat/namehistory

To be clear, I want in an array the following:

- TripleThreat
- [FD] TripleThreat.blyat
- 9

and so on..

I have already tried writing the Regex but it was a disaster (Something I struggle with)

Here's what I wrote:

```
$page = file_get_contents(sprintf("http://steamcommunity.com/id/TripleThreat/namehistory"));

preg_match_all("/<span class=\"historyDash\">-<\/span>((.|\n)*)<\/div>/", $page, $matches);

foreach($matches[0] as $match) {
    echo($match . "<br/>");
}
```

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: I did look for an API to retrieve the data, but found nothing, scraping is the only option it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following regex (the match is in the first capturing group):

```
"/<span class=\"historyDash\">-<\/span>\s*((?:[^\<]|\n)*?)\s*<\/div>/"
```

See it on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yM6uK0/3).

The changes I made: trimmed whitespace before and after with the `\s*`, changed the `.` to `[^\<]` to choose only the ones that aren't tag (i.e., the correct text).

---

**Note**: As @PedroLobito pointed out, [don't parse HTML with regex unless necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2397327). Use [a library to parse the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php) instead when you can. I just provided an easy example to extend your work, but it might not be the best solution.

Comment: never use regex to parse html, bad example.

Comment: @PedroLobito Good point, I'll mention that in my answer. Edited now.